# Ramanujan’s puzzling problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory

**Question:**

$$ f_1 (x) = \sqrt {1+\sqrt {x} } $$
$$ f_2 (x) = \sqrt{1+ \sqrt {1+2 \sqrt {x} } } $$
$$ f_3 (x) = \sqrt {1+ \sqrt {1+2 \sqrt {1+3 \sqrt {x} } } } $$
... and so on to
$$ f_n (x) = \sqrt {1+\sqrt{1+2 \sqrt {1+3 \sqrt {\ldots \sqrt {1+n \sqrt {x} } } } } } $$
Evaluate this function as n tends to infinity.

Or logically:
Find
$ \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} f_n (x) $ .

**MyProblem:**
Ramanujan discovered
$$ x+n+a=\sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 +x \sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2 +(x+n) \sqrt{\ldots}}} $$
which gives the special cases
$$ x+1=\sqrt{1+x \sqrt{1 + (x+1) \sqrt{1 + (x+2) \sqrt{1 + (x+2) \sqrt{\ldots}}}}}$$
for x=2 , n=1 and a=0
$$3= \sqrt{1+2 \sqrt{1+3 \sqrt{1+ 4 \sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}$$

*Is there any proof of this discovery?Without proof I don’t think that the problem should be solved in this way.And if there is a proof please share it and also tell your approach to solve it.*

Comment: Formally you have $f_{n+1}(x) = f_n(1+(n+1)\sqrt{x})$. Anyway I don't see any obvious solution.

Comment: I find this problem highly intriguing and a solution to problem is essential since we can’t rely on theories which have no proofs.

Comment: @kingW3 for your kind information I am not asking for a solution here.i am questioning the foundation of this discovery.Before declaring possible duplicates please read the understand what I am asking from the users of this community.

Comment: Ramanujan was literally a ducking genius! 

Comment: Yes that is without a doubt.But some things need to be challenged to get a complete understanding of their theories.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer The first answer there provides the info I think you're looking for, consider looking at the linked question(answer).

Comment: Ok I went through it .

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer Does it answer what you're looking for?

Comment: No since his solution is incomplete and further discussion about this problem is written in an article.When I clicked on the link I selected to read the article for free and was asked to register an account to read it.So actually my question is still unanswered.

Comment: Yes I got it now.Click this link to read the supportive article on this proof :-https://gauravtiwari.org/nested/